# c# How Do I make Sure Webclient allows necessary time for download

Tags: c#

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                     html = client.DownloadString(some_string);
                     //do something
                     html = client.DownloadString(some_string1);
                     //do something
html = client.DownloadString(some_string2);
                     //do something
html = client.DownloadString(some_string3);
                     //do something
etc
                }
```

webclient does not allow itself enough time to download the entire source of the webpage. how do i force it to wait until it finishes the donwload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DownloadString is a blocking call, so there is no need to do anything. It will continue to download until the string is received.

The problem probably lies in the fact that you shouldn't be using DownloadString. What are you trying to retrieve? Do you end up with half of your expected string?

You should probably use it as the MSDN article shows:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();

// Add a user agent header in case the 
// requested URI contains a query.

client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

Stream data = client.OpenRead (some_string);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
Console.WriteLine (s);
data.Close ();
reader.Close ();
```

The source is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx

Comment: i just went to fetch the source of a webpage

Comment: In that case, the code above should be fine. MSDN does not say exactly what will be downloaded if you use DownloadString. I would also check your page is not downloading an error message or similar. It's asking a webserver to give you the page (just like your browser does), so it's possible if you give it an incorrect URL that you will end up downloading a "Page could not be found" message.

Comment: thanks for the tip the mighty streamreader comes to the rescue once again.

Answer (score 1):

The web client doesn't allow programmatic access to Timeout. You'll have to use a HttpRequest object instead.